# What is the correct HTML semantic tag for generated data in a list?

Tags: html, semantics

If I want to generate a receipt for users, what tag should I use for purchase date, item, cost etc.

I know I'll use labels for the categories.

```
<ul>
    <li> <label> Item </label> <span> Poster(is span correct for this area?) </span> </li>
    <li> <label> Date </label> <span> XX/XX/20XX </span> </li>
    <li> <label> Cost </label> <span> $10 </span> </li>
</ul>
```

Is Span a good one? Or something else

And if not really, then I guess I can resort the backup

```
<ul>
    <li> <label> Item </label>  Poster(is span correct for this area?)  </li>
    <li> <label> Date </label>  XX/XX/20XX </li>
    <li> <label> Cost </label>  $10 </li>
</ul>
```

Where I format all the text as I want towards the generated date, but add another layer of styling with the label tag.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<label>` is not valid in that context, [The label element represents a caption for a form control](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/label.html#label).

I'd just use `<strong>`:

```
<ul>
    <li><strong>Item:</strong> Poster</li>
    <li><strong>Date:</strong> XX/XX/20XX</li>
    <li><strong>Cost:</strong> $10</li>
</ul>
```

Or a table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Item</th><td>Poster</td>
        <th scope="row">Date</th><td>XX/XX/20XX</td>
        <th scope="row">Cost</th><td>$10</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out **[HTML5's Microformats](http://microformats.org/wiki/html5)**. For the date you could use `<datetime>`

Answer (score 0):

**Semantics**

I would also say that a `<table>` or a **microformat** would fit best for your data as this is not really a list of items.

**span-Tag**

And I like to add, that a `<span>`-tag has no semantic meaning - it's "[Semantically neutral](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Generic_containers_-_the_div_and_span_elements#Semantically_neutral)". If you want to **emphasize** text simply use the `<em>`- or `<strong>`-tags.